# SwiftUI WebRTC Audio and Video rendering

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, webrtc-ios

I have a problem with integrating Audio and Video from WebRTC to SwiftUI View. 
Im trying to do this with UIViewRepresentable, but catch an error. About audio streaming i have no idea.
My SwiftUI View:

```
        if showingVideo {
            //MARK: SHOW VIDEO, AND TURN ON AUDIO

        } else {

        }
```

My try with using UIViewRepresentable

```
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> RTCEAGLVideoView  {
        self.remoteView.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 200, height: 300)
        self.remoteView = self.video.remoteVideoView!
        return self.remoteView
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you should init remoteView in makeUIView, just need to return it when setup full needed property.

Comment: @HồngPhúc , you right really thank you <3, is help me, but can you help me with audio?

Comment: i don't have experience in WebRTC, so I can't point you the way to do it

Answer (score 0):

The answer is doing something like this

```
@ObservedObject var videoCallController: VideoCallController
func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
    let remoteRenderer = RTCEAGLVideoView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.videoCallController.webRTCClient.renderRemoteVideo(to: remoteRenderer)

}
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> RTCEAGLVideoView {
    let remoteRenderer = RTCEAGLVideoView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.videoCallController.webRTCClient.renderRemoteVideo(to: remoteRenderer)
    return remoteRenderer
}
```

Where render remote video is

```
func renderRemoteVideo(to renderer: RTCVideoRenderer) {
    self.remoteVideoTrack?.add(renderer)
}
```

Remote video track is RTCVideoTrack.